# SQLite SELECT and UITableView

Tags: ios, performance, sqlite, select

I need to show on a UITableView with sections all the values from a sqlite table. The table has 100 000 rows. Everything is working fine except that it takes almost 5 seconds until the data appears. I understand this happens due to the large number of rows. Thus, I decided to reload the table view every 10 000 rows. For each 10 000 rows, the methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

are called and return the correct value, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath`is never called except at the end of the full selection (100 000). I'm currently executing the sql query on the main thread. Is that why the table view doesn't get updated or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching the Database all before the table have a chance to load, yes splitting it won't change anything. And the main thread is the UI thread, so blocking it with long sql fetching will delay the loading of your table view.

You don't need to have 100 000 rows to be able to display at most 10 - 20 rows on screen.

Why not just have a fetch for the count in `numberOfRowsInSection` and make a fetch for 1000 element in cellForRowAtIndexPath (or less) the idea would be to get what you need to display as fast as possible then fetch for the rest of your data as needed. 
Like if the person is scrolling and you have 1000 rows and the person scroll to row 700, that could be the time to fetch an other 1000.
Depending on what your application is doing and how often the scroling need to be done, that could be a way to do it.

Comment: The problem is that I have sections. You're suggesting I just get the first n rows for each section, right? Let's say the user is at letter A and it taps letter Z. Then he scrolls up and he will be at letter Y. The data for those cells won't be available yet.

Comment: @adriana I'm suggesting : just get what you need to display + a little breathing room at first, so you can present something to the user as quickly as possible then fetch the rest, as needed or all at once.